# Solaris 11-CBE and pci-e Serial adapter

Tags: solaris

I have installed [this serial adapter](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00GT65XME/) on Solaris 11.4 (CBE)

prtconf report it

```
prtconf -vdup|ggrep -i serial -A 11
                model:  '16850-compatible serial controller'
                pcie-bdf:  '03:00.0'
                power-consumption:  00000001.00000001
                reg:  00030000.00000000.00000000.00000000.00000000.01030010.00000000.00000000.00000000.00000100.42030014.00000000.00000000.00000000.00008000.01030018.00000000.00000000.00000000.00000004
                revision-id:  00000010
                subsystem-id:  00003253
                subsystem-vendor-id:  00001c00
                unit-address:  '0'
                vendor-id:  00001c00
                name:  'pci1c00,3253'
```

But I cannot see the serial ports

```
ls /dev/tty[ab]
gls: cannot access '/dev/tty[ab]': No such file or directory
```

The adapter is not supported, or there is still hope to see it working on Solaris?

Comment: Should you not be looking for `/dev/ttyS[0-9]`? It's been years since I handled Solaris.

Comment: on Solaris /dev/ttya is ttyS0 under Linux, ttyb is ttyS1, etc when serial adapter is recognized ttya[bc] is created

Comment: Hohum! You learn something new everyday... I think I'm teaching you to suck eggs, but a search says to run `Device Configuration Assistant`.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think DCA is supported on Solaris 11, most probably the controller is not supported by Solaris drivers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Solution" found. The card is not supported by Solaris driver